# Timeout an internet-connectivity check

Tags: asp-classic, timeout, freeze, connectivity, internet-connection

I have a Classic ASP web app that is meant to run OFFLINE 99% of the time (in rural areas with no internet service).

When the app does have a connection to the internet, it alerts the user so he/she/they can synchronize data with the ONLINE version of the web app.

I have a detection function that works very well when there is internet service, immediately detecting the internet.

```
'CHECK FOR AN INTERNET CONNECTION
    WITH CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://xxx.xxxx-xxxxx.org", FALSE
        .SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)"
        ON Error RESUME NEXT
        .Send
        IF .waitForReponse(2) THEN
            IF .Status = 200 THEN 
                strOnline = "Y"
            ELSE
                strOnline = "N"
            END IF 
        ELSE
            strOnline = "N"
        END IF
    END WITH
END IF
```

The problem is that, when there is no internet service, the script makes the page hang for around 12 seconds before loading.

As you can see above, I tried enclosing the check in .WaitForResponse(), but it doesn't seem to be having any effect.

What can I do to cancel the connectivity check if no internet is found in the first 1 or 2 seconds?

Comment: I've changed "IF .WaitForResponse(2) THEN " to "IF ERR.NUMBER <> 0 THEN" and the page is loading slightly faster (7 seconds vs. 12 seconds). Still, this is not the solution I'm looking for. I want it to simply timeout if it doesn't get a response in less than 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation, I found a solution that I like and that has stood up to significant stress testing:

```
strOnline = "N"
    Const WAIT_TIMEOUT = 2
    Dim http
    Set http = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        http.open "POST", "http://172.217.4.132", TRUE 'async request
        http.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)"
        http.send 
        IF ERR.NUMBER <> 0 THEN
            strOnline = "N"
        ELSE
            IF http.waitForResponse(WAIT_TIMEOUT) THEN 'response ready
                strOnline = "Y"
            ELSE 'wait timeout exceeded
                strOnline = "N" 
            END IF
        END IF 
    SET http = NOTHING
```

I sincerely hope that helps someone else. Cheers, N

Comment: The significant change would appear to be that you switched from the HTTP GET verb to POST. Correct ?

Comment: And also that I switched from "MSXML2.XMLHTTP" to "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP"

Comment: ok - what's the difference there, apart from the time effect?

Comment: The time effect is the who point. My old script was very quick at determining if there is an internet connection but would hang for 12 secs before determining that there wasn't one. I needed to eliminate that lag.

Comment: Sure - I was wondering if the time reduction was due to using POST or the switch to MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.

Comment: I think it's because MSXML2.XMLHTTP can't really use .waitForResponse, whereas MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP can, but I could be totally off. Another thing I did was change the URL from "www.google.com" to the IP Address for that URL. Maybe that had an effect too?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the perfect answer to making that code run faster. Instead it is an alternative for a better long-term solution.

TLDR: Make this check into a plain browser-side async JS function, or use an ASP 'page' that is sessionless and call it via the same async JS approach.

Longer explanation: I assume this code is running on the local server, kicked off by the users browser possibly as an include at the 'top' of each ASP page file. You want to try to remove any long-running ASP code from page builds as each small processing delay hurts the perceived performance.

In this case you are just checking if the internet connection is available and informing the user. You could do this with a plain JS function embedded into the head of every page you send to the browser and avoid the need to use ASP for this function entirely. Just make the JS async try to access the internet-based server. If you get a 200 then the internet is up, if its a 400 or similar then its down.

If you absolutely 'have' to stick to ASP, then you can lift this function into separate ASP file and use the same JS async technique to call it, making the ASP sessionless with the inclusion of

```
<%@ ENABLESESSIONSTATE=False %>
```

at the top of the file. Requests for session-based ASP pages run in a sequential queue, so going sessionless stops this request from blocking the queue.

Summary - get the server check out of the 'every=page' flow of ASP, ideally get it out of ASP all together and make it plain JS.

Comment: Really grateful for your lengthy reply. What I'm really trying to get out of the internet-connectivity check is the ability to set a VBS variable strOffiline as either "Y" or "N". How could I do that with the JS async request?